# python 3, unicode conversion, two \u0000 as one character

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

My python3 script receives strings from c++ program via pipe.
Strings encoded via Unicode code points. I need to decode it correctly.

For example, consider string that contain cyrillic symbols: `'тест test'`

Try to encode this string using python3: `print('тест test'.encode())`. We got `b'\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 test'`

C++ program encodes this string like: `b'\u00D1\u0082\u00D0\u00B5\u00D1\u0081\u00D1\u0082 test'`

Encoded strings looks very similar - python3 uses `\x` (2bits) and c++ program uses `\u` (4bits).
But I can't figure out how to convert `b'\u00D1\u0082\u00D0\u00B5\u00D1\u0081\u00D1\u0082 test'` to `'тест test'`.
Main problem - python3 consider `b'\u00D1\u0082\u00D0\u00B5\u00D1\u0081\u00D1\u0082'` as 8-character string, but it contain only 4 characters

Comment: Show your C++ encoding code.  It looks like it stored the encoded bytes in a `wchar_t` array, which is incorrect.

Comment: I don't have sources of c++ program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string you receive from C++ is the following in Python:

```
s = b'\u00D1\u0082\u00D0\u00B5\u00D1\u0081\u00D1\u0082 test'
```

Then this will decode it:

```
result = s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
тест test
```

The first stage converts the byte string received into a Unicode string:

```
>>> s1 = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> s1
'Ñ\x82ÐµÑ\x81Ñ\x82 test'
```

Unfortunately, the Unicode codepoints are really UTF-8 byte values.  The `latin1` encoding is a 1:1 mapping of the first 256 Unicode codepoints, so encoding with this codec converts the codepoints back to byte values in a byte string:

```
>>> s2 = s1.encode('latin1')
>>> s2
b'\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 test'
```

Now the byte string can be decoded to the correct Unicode string:

```
>>> s3 = s2.decode('utf8')
>>> s3
'тест test'
```

Comment: It works! I had no chance to figure out this solution by myself. Thank you very much ))